# How to solve java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database.in pyspark 2.2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am developing a spark-flask  application in pyspark . I am using pyspark 2.20 Here is my code

```
import re
from tkinter import*
import json

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
#from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from flask import Flask
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
conf=SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName("TestValue")
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext=HiveContext(sc)
#from pyspark.sql import Row




app=Flask(__name__)
#spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:\spark\spark-warehouse").appName("TestApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
print("Success")

#sqlstring="SELECT lflow1.LeaseType as LeaseType, lflow1.Status as Status, lflow1.Property as property, lflow1.City as City, lesflow2.DealType as DealType, lesflow2.Area as Area, lflow1.Did as DID, lesflow2.MID as MID from lflow1, lesflow2  WHERE lflow1.Did = lesflow2.MID"
@app.route('/<sqlval>')
def queryBuilder(sqlval):
    df=sqlContext.sql(sqlval)
    #df.show()

    resultlist = df.toJSON().collect()
    dumpdata = re.sub(r"\'", "", str(resultlist))
    jsondata = json.dumps(dumpdata)
    #print(jsondata)
    return jsondata

    #return df

#queryBuilder(sqlstring)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)

master=Tk()
entryval=Entry(master)
entryval.grid(row=0,column=1)
Button(master,text='Quit',command=master.quit).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W,pady=50)
mainloop()
```

Here i have coded  sqlCOntext style instead of sparksession.builder. this code is expected to return json data response as per request. and now I am gettting bellow error

**java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app)**

It was the nested last exception in stacktrace. the original exception was
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@7af1b8e6, see the 
next exception for detail

Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\spark\metastore_db.

i have deleted db.lck file from metastore_db folder  but nothing changed. I have used this tricks before for solving  last two exception. but did not face

*java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app)*

So far i have figure out that it was a bug in spark 2.0.1, 2.0.2 and it was fixed in 2.1 and 2.2 version
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18687

and i am using pyspark 2.2 version now in windows 10

Here is the code of Spark session style

```
from tkinter import*
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from flask import Flask
import json
import re
app=Flask(__name__)
spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:\spark\spark-warehouse")\
    .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")\
    .appName("TestApp").\
    enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
#spark.conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")
#spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true").appName("TestApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
print("Success")

#sqlstring="SELECT lflow1.LeaseType as LeaseType, lflow1.Status as Status, lflow1.Property as property, lflow1.City as City, lesflow2.DealType as DealType, lesflow2.Area as Area, lflow1.Did as DID, lesflow2.MID as MID from lflow1, lesflow2  WHERE lflow1.Did = lesflow2.MID"
@app.route('/<sqlval>')
def queryBuilder(sqlval):
    df=spark.sql(sqlval)
    #df.show()

    resultlist = df.toJSON().collect()
    dumpdata = re.sub(r"\'", "", str(resultlist))
    jsondata = json.dumps(dumpdata)
    #print(jsondata)
    return jsondata

    #return df

#queryBuilder(sqlstring)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)

master=Tk()
entryval=Entry(master)
entryval.grid(row=0,column=1)
Button(master,text='Quit',command=master.quit).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W,pady=50)
mainloop()
```

Stacktrace images

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your metastore is already used somewhere. So you have to remove *.lck files form your metastore folder (C:spark\metastore_db).

Comment: i did remove it . lol it was old trick. but now nothing changed :D

Answer (score 0):

hive.metastore.warehouse.dir property in hive-site.xml is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0. Instead, use spark.sql.warehouse.dir to specify the default location of database in warehouse. Then restart spark-shell.